# How to Fix SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported in IIS 6.0

Tags: pci-dss, pci-compliance

We tested the application for PCI Compliance and ended up with an error stating that

```
                **SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported**
```

And the solution for this is given as

```
Reconfigure the affected application if possible to avoid use of medium strength ciphers
```

Can anyone help me how to implement in windows server 2003 using IIS 6.0

Answer (score 3):

Go to the following location from registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\

You will see a list of cipher key size.

Add a new DWORD key name 'Enabled' with value '0' to the cipher key with the size less than '128'.

Hope this help.

Myo Zaw.